# Understand xmlns , xmlns:somePreFix , targetNamespace in the XSD

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xml-namespaces

I just tried to understand these 3 attributes in `XSD` definition. But not sure if it is right . Please help to correct me .If it is wrong. Thanks

Compared to the `Java Class` definition with XSD definition.

The `targetNamespace` just like package definition of Java Class. Indicating all the members including fields , properties and Class are belong to the `targetNamespace`.

And we need import some class members from other class for consuming them. So That is the `xmlns` and `xmlns:somePreFix` work for. and `xmlns` is just a default one.

Comment: You are on right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, **targetNamespace**  tells which scope do all the elements of  your xsd reside in. It is similar to a package but not exactly same as the tags inside the xml file also reside in that targetNamespace. On the other hand, in Java the instance variables/methods do not belong to the package directly, they belong to the class.

**xmlns:somePrefix** provides a convenient "somePrefix" alias to the imported xml schema's namespace. xmlns does not not actually import the members of targetNamepace for which we have a separate xsd:import tag. Rather, it is just referring to the namespace. You can of course use it in conjunction with an xsd:import to have an "java import like" effect.